# How can I make relational database in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, relational-database

I'm working on very big scale projects. Finally, I've chosen Android and Firebase due to user friendliness and simplicity. I'm going to have multiple children like following:

```
products
 1
 name: 
"p1"
 2
 name: 
"p2"


 route
 1: 
"xyz"
 2: 
"abx"
```

Here is one user case:
If user updates route 1 and puts 'john' instead of 'xyz', then name 1 should be updated to 'x1' instead of 'p1'.

One of the way is to do it programatically via android to use methods like 'ondatachange()' But I want to do it on the server side. I don't want to write each time when route 'x' gets updated product 'a' should update in android app.

How can we build relational database on firebase?

Remember there won't be just two tables but there will be 50+ key-value pairs.

Comment: Will there be multiple databases, or multiple children within one database? The Realtime Database doesn't lend itself well to what you are describing, but it is still possible. I just want to clarify before I give a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry my typo! Its 'children' not databases. There will be multiple children and their multiple sub-children to 'app-name' database.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that you won't want to do all that work client-side! Cloud Functions for Firebase are a good option. You can trigger a function on a write to a path in the database, and then make the change to the other related paths. Check out these resources to find out more:

[Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ)

[GitHub samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

[Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Writing a Database Trigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0&t=22s)

[Writing a Cloud Storage Trigger: Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDLpEn3PbmE)

[Writing a Cloud Storage Trigger: Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lzEgwiSs-M&t=1s)

Comment: Jen, thank you and the rest of the Firebase team for such great videos!!  I would probably also link to this series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s with emphasis on denormalization and to use the cloud functions to propagate updates.

Comment: Thank you so much Jen! I'll definately discuss with my dev team and get back to you! Would like if you can upvote my question!

Comment: Sure thing, John! And let me know if you have any additional questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase admin sdk or firebase functions to listen on changes.
The code will look something like this :

```
exports.routeUpdated = functions.database.ref("route/{id}").onWrite(event => {
    // read the event value/s you need
    const id = // id of the product you want to update
    let updates = {};
    //set updates like updates['/name'] = ...
    admin.database().ref('products/' + id).update(updates).then(() => {
        //...
    }); });
```